# pub get failed: Because flutter_app depends on firebase_firestore ^0.12.7+1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, dependencies

> ```
>  pub get failed: Because flutter_app depends on firebase_firestore
>  ^0.12.7+1 which doesn't match any versions, version solving failed.
> ```

I am getting this error when trying to run `flutter pub get` in the pubspec.yaml file. I am currently trying to set up firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup.

This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

  # Add the dependency for the Firebase Core Flutter SDK
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0+1

  # Add the dependency for the FlutterFire plugin for Google Analytics
  firebase_analytics: ^4.0.2

  # Add the dependencies for any other Firebase products you want to use in your app
  # For example, to use Firebase Authentication and Cloud Firestore
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+3
  firebase_firestore: ^0.12.7+1

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle app:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.flutter_app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have noticed that the second build.gradle file contains several marked errors, but I am not sure if that means anything.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

firebase_firestore package is deprecated and the last version it has is 0.0.3+1... so it cannot find version ^0.12.7+1

You will need to cloud_firestore instead:

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore

Try following the latest Firebase codelab from the Flutter team.

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/firebase

Comment: Would I then write `cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7+1` in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Hi @jonasxd360 you can try that. However, there might be significant changes to the package. So if you still are getting errors.. better checkout the codelab link above... it should be compatible with the latest Flutter version.

Comment: Yeah, I got a multidex problem, but I think I solved it using multiDexEnabled true and implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
firebase_firestore: ^0.12.7+1
```

With

```
firebase_firestore: any
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this plugin in your `pubspec.yaml`. It should work.

```
firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14
```